Execute a github actions workflow after 3 hours of completion
I am using github actions to run a python script programmatically.
I need to be able to run the script every 3 hours, but I need those 3 hours to start counting from the time the execution ends.
That is, if my script starts running at 05:00 and finishes at 05:10, then the next execution should start at 08:10. If I set it every 3 hours with cron, in the case of my example the next execution would be at 08:00 and not at 08:10.
I tried setting a time sleep of 3 hours in the YAML but this would imply consuming a lot of time from what github gives you for free.
I tried setting a time sleep of 3 hours in the YAML but this would imply consuming a lot of time from what github gives you for free.

One builtin option is to use the wait timers feature when using environments.

Use a wait timer to delay a job for a specific amount of time after the job is initially triggered. The time (in minutes) must be an integer between 1 and 43,200 (30 days).

You can specify the job that should run in 3 hours by using an environment with a wait timer of 180 minutes.
If you have wiggle room in how precise this must be, another option is to create an Action schedule to run on a much higher frequency, as little as every 5 minutes. The scheduled job can be scripted to check whether 3 hours has elapsed (or whatever other conditions you may have). You would still consume something like a minute or two every 5 minutes, but it's potentially less costly than waiting the full 3 hours.
